# What does $F^{\times 2}$ mean, for $F$ Field

Tags: field-theory, notation, quaternions

I would love some explanation regarding this notation, seen in "Quaternion Algebras" by John Voight, https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat-book.pdf
in Prop. 2.2.10 and 2.2.14

Let $F$ be a field of $char \neq 2$ and $F^\times$ it's set of invertable elements, what is $F^{\times 2}$ ?

Comment: Would interpreting it as $(F^\times)^2 = F^\times\times F^\times$ make sense in context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This refers to the set of square elements of $F^\times$, that is the set of $x\in F^\times$ such that $x=y^2$ for some $y\in F^\times$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, yes, in general if $G$ is an abelian group written multiplicatively and $n$ is a positive integer, I write $G^n := \{g^n : g \in G\} \leq G$ for the subgroup of $n$th powers.  Here, $G=F^\times$ and we drop the parentheses $F^{\times 2} = (F^\times)^2$.